# Android Calenderview Need Sun instead of S for sunday

Tags: android, android-studio, calendarview

Am using a CalenderView in my project. When I run the program the weeks are S, M, T etc for Sunday, Monday, Tuesday etc.
I need Sun, Mon, Tue.. instead of single characters like S, M etc. Is it possible?
 Please help.

This is my XML.

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="2"
    android:weekSeparatorLineColor="@color/gray"/>
```

Comment: Would you please provide the xml design and code you have tried.

Comment: Use this Library For Customization. https://github.com/square/android-times-square

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

This library seems really nice and with a more modern UI (Material Design) :

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

You just have to import it with gradle:

```
implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.0'
```

And add it in your layout:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="2"
    android:weekSeparatorLineColor="@color/gray" 
    />
```